# TNTUnicode components problem

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-2007

I downloaded and tried installed the TNT Delphi Unicode components. I use Code Gear Delphi 2007.

Then I opened the TntUnicodeVcl_D70.dpk and tried to build it. The following message appeared

**The following changes must be made before this package can be compiled. 
Choose OK to apply these changes and continue compiling

Remove TntActnList, TntButtons, TntComCtrls, TntDBCtrls, TntDialogs, TntExtCtrls, TntExtDlgs, TntForms, TntGrids, TntMenus, TntStdCtrls.
Unit(s) TntActnList, TntButtons, TntComCtrls, TntDBCtrls, TntDialogs, TntExtCtrls, TntExtDlgs, TntForms, TntGrids, TntMenus, TntStdCtrls were found in required package TntUnicodeVcl_R70.**

I clicked the OK button and then an access violation message appeared making the compilation and consequently the installation impossible.

**Access violation at address 21665A in module 'delphicoreide100.bpl'. Read of address 0000004.**

Could somebody please help me to overcome this situation?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

`TntUnicodeVcl_R70.dpk` and `TntUnicodeVcl_D70.dpk` are for Delphi 7, hense why they are located in the `\Delphi\D7` folder to begin with.  For Delphih 2007, use `TntUnicodeVcl.bdsproj` and `TntUnicodeVcl_Design.bdsproj` in the `\Delphi\bds4` folder instead.

Comment: THANK YOU EVER SO MUCH REMY!!!!!!! 

I followed your instructions and now everything got installed. It accepted the design .dpk

THANK YOU AGAIN!!!